# How to repeat back char from bash?

Tags: bash

Have a bottom progress bar with:

```
progressbar="Search ${i_register} of ${n_registers} profiles ... ${full_name}";
echo $progressbar;
...
# delete progressbar
# write extra outputs
# re-write progressbar
...
```

i try this with \b but need repeat \b n times when n is equals to:

```
progress_length=$(($(echo $progressbar | wc -m) - 1));
```

I try with:

```
echo "aaa" && printf "\b%.0s" {1..100}
echo "aaa" && seq -s"\b" 100|tr -d '[:digit:]'
```

But does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too much work.

```
for i in {0..100} ; do printf "\r%s%%" "$i" ; sleep 0.1 ; done ; echo
```

Comment: Plus one, though you probably don't actually want to continue sleeping after you've reached 100% . . .

Comment: Sure. That was just a demonstration.